# What versioning filesystem?

Tags: software-recommendation

I'd like to (automatically) keep previous versions of files that I'm working on when saved, without using explicit 'commits' to git or other VCS, and without changing the name of the saved file.

Currently there are several tools to sync folders to clouds or to your own NAS, that are also maintaining the file versions, so I could use those.
But if I don't need or want to save to cloud/NAS and I'd like to have only the bare-bone versioning filesystem functionality, is there anything that I can use in a recent Linux environment?

It seems there have been some attempts in the past to build something like svnfs and gitfs, but I did not find any complete and tested solution. Do you know any?

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is a [Versioning File System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Versioning_file_system). The Wikipaedia lists several open source implementations for Linux, although none seems to be fully mature at this stage:

- [ext3cow](http://www.ext3cow.com/)
- [Next3](http://next3.sourceforge.net/)
- [NILFS](http://nilfs.org/)
- [Tux3](http://tux3.org/)

To me it seems far easier to use a mainstream versioning system with auto-commit set on desired files and/or folders. You can check how to do it at [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/420143/making-git-auto-commit).

Comment: Of those, only NILFS seems to be in active development (as of 2014). [This answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/115397/how-do-i-install-12-04-onto-a-nilfs-root-partition) seems to provide the instructions to use it, though I haven't tested it.

Answer (score 0):

You can check [gifts](https://github.com/PressLabs/gitfs). We are using it in production for some months now and looks stable.